# How to disable warnings?

Tags: perl

I have warning:

```
"my" variable $subject masks earlier declaration in same scope at ...
```

I know that I can disable warning via `no warnings 'all'` pragma, but can not find [right category](https://perldoc.pl/warnings#Category-Hierarchy) for my type of warnings.

How to disable only this type of warning?

Comment: What is the reason that you re-declare same variable second time in same scope?

Comment: Please don't turn off that warning, and fix the problem instead!

Comment: @ikegami: I just do not want to comment code which I temporary want to disable. (to make commits more clear)

Comment: In that case, it's best to leave the warning to help avoid leaving the hack in place!

Comment: @ikegami: I track that in another place, so I disable warnings to not flood logs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Search [`perldoc perldiag`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldiag) for your warning message. This one [turns up](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldiag#%22%s%22-variable-%s-masks-earlier-declaration-in-same-%s)

> **"%s" variable &%s masks earlier declaration in same %s**
>
> (W shadow) A "my", "our" or "state" variable has been redeclared in the current scope or statement, effectively eliminating all access to the previous instance. This is almost always a typographical error. Note that the earlier variable will still exist until the end of the scope or until all closure references to it are destroyed.

which tells you that the pragma to disable this specific warning is

```
no warnings 'shadow';
```

Comment: Along with that, you can say `use diagnostics;` in your program and you'll get the long version of the warning.

Comment: Prior to perl v5.28, this warning is in the `misc` category.

Answer (score 5):

> How to disable only this type of warning?

Please don't do that. It's a far better idea to fix the bug that is causing the error.

You've declared `$subject` twice. Either remove the `my` from the second declaration or change the name of the second variable. I know nothing about your code, so I can't advise you on which approach is best.

Comment: Or limit the scope of the variables (by moving code into blocks or into subs).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wouldn't disable warnings at all. There is a good reason that they warn you about that. I would suggest that you look at how to prevent the warning and not deactivate them. If you want, post the code and let other people help you!

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons to disable selected warnings.

Comment: I can see your point but in my opinion, there are plenty of better reasons to not disable any of those.